# getting autocompletion in SQL in the SELECT clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, autocomplete, psql

When using Postgres through the `psql` command line client, you can use tab completion in the `WHERE` clause.  For example, a "users" table with an "email" and "age" column, you could type:

```
SELECT age FROM users WHERE em<TAB>
```

Would give you

```
SELECT age FROM users WHERE email
```

However, this doesn't work in the `SELECT` clause.  Typing:

```
SELECT em<TAB>
```

does **NOT** give you

```
SELECT email
```

Of course it doesn't work because it doesn't yet know what table to peer into for the the tab completion, but is there *some* way to do this?  I tried switching the order of the sql statement to

```
FROM users SELECT em<TAB>
```

But that neither works, nor appears to be a legal SQL statement (it throws an error when executing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this in psql. But is supported in some IDE, i.e. [https://www.jetbrains.com/idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) (only ultimate edition) and [valentina db studio](http://www.valentina-db.com/en/). (I only use Intellj Idea - and psql :) - and don't know other IDEs but probably this feature is supported by the most IDEs).